# How can i run XPathBuilder in Sitecore 9

Tags: sitecore-client

How can I run XPathBuilder in Sitecore 9?

I already tried this URL from earlier versions of Sitecore, but it is not working in Sitecore 9: `http://<website>/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=IDE.XPath.Builder`

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not. XPath Builder has been removed in Sitecore 9.

You could try **Sitecore Powershell Extensions** (SPE). It can help you with the queries and do a whole lot more...

An example of the query functionality in Sitecore 9 with PowerShell:

```
Get-Item -Path master:// -Query "/sitecore/content//*[@@TemplateName = 'Sample Item']"
```

More info: 
https://www.sitecorespark.com/blog/2017/11/xpath-builder-sitecore-9-powershell-option

Answer (score 4):

XPath Builder has been removed in Sitecore 9.

One alternative is to use Query Analyzer from Sitecore Rocks.

To open Query analizer after you install Sitecore Rocks go to **Tools-> Query Analizer**

[image]

Here are described some of queries which can be run :

https://sitecoreknowledgeshare.blogspot.com/2016/04/sitecore-rocks-query-analyzer.html

Comment: Under Query Analyer in latest Sitecore Rocks, there is an XPath Builder too!